# How to fix stuck aperture?

Tags: lens, aperture, repair, diy

I have a Micro-Nikkor 55 mm 1:2.8 lens. The aperture appears to be stuck. Is it worth trying to repair the lens? Are there any good guides for disassembling the lens?

Comment: Have you contacted Nikon? They may have a solution that you can do yourself.

Comment: Take to repair shop for evaluation/repair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a search, I have found a useful [disassembly guide](http://kf0rt.westton.com/lens/lens.htm) for the lens. However I discourage you from fixing it yourself as dust or fungi spores could be introduced onto the lenses.

Comment: especially if you do it on the carpet!!! (see link above)